# Backend is not working in Heroku after deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, server, backend

Backend is working on the localhost:5000 but it doesn't work when I upload the backend on Heroku. I saw many videos on YouTube to see how to run the backend online on Heroku but none of the video helped me. I am a newbie I have started from scratch. I am giving my backend code. please check and tell me where I am wrong.

index.js

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db'); // Get the access from ('./db') to access the connectToMongo() function that is created in that component
const express = require('express')
require("dotenv").config();
var cors = require('cors')

// Call the connectToMongo() function in main file to access the database by the backend
connectToMongo();
const app = express()
// I can change the port anytime so I can't get confuse in different files when I run them 
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors())
// To send the JSON body request to database and read it in database
app.use(express.json())

// Available Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'))
app.use('/api/notes', require('./routes/notes'))

// Validation that the port is running
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`iNotebook backend listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

This is my backend-end

```
router.post(
  "/login",
  [
    body("email", "Enter a valid email").isEmail(),
    body("password", "Password cannot be blank").exists(),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    let success = false;
    // If there are errors return bad request and the errors
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ success, error: "Please try to login with correct credentials" });
      }

      const passwordCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!passwordCompare) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ success, error: "Please try to login with correct credentials" });
      }

      const data = {
        user: {
          id: user.id,
        },
      };
      const authtoken = jwt.sign(data, JWT_SECRET);
      // console.log(authtoken);
      success = true;
      res.json({ success, authtoken });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
  }
);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "inotebook-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "iNotebook - Your notebook on the cloud",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

login.js front-end

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Login = (props) => {
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({ email: "", password: "" })
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e, email, password) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login", {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password }) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    if (json.success) {
      //   Save the auth token and redirect
      localStorage.setItem('token', json.authtoken);
      // navigate("/") page will be redirected to this location after login
      navigate("/ShowNotes");
      props.showAlert("Logged in Successfully!", "success ");

    }
    else {
      props.showAlert("Invalid Credenetails", "danger");
    }
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="loginBody">
        <div className="loginHead">
          <div className="loginSection">
            <h2 className='loginHeading'>Login</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="loginBox">
            {/* <div className='loginPage'> */}
            <form className='loginForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-3 my-2">
                <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label login-email-label">Email address :</label>
                <input type="email" className="email-input" id="email" name="email" onChange={onChange} value={credentials.email} aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
                {/* <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div> */}
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3 my-2 ">
                <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label login-password-label">Password :</label>
                <input type="password" className="password-input" name="password" onChange={onChange} value={credentials.password} id="password" />
              </div>
              <div className="loginPageBtnSection">
                <button type="submit" className="loginPageBtn"><i className="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </form>
            {/* </div> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: What error is thrown or shown?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at handleSubmit (Login.js:10:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in this part:

```
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login", {
```

You're calling `localhost`, which works on your local machine. If you're using Heroku, it's not localhost.

**Why:** Heroku assigns your project a unique url/ domain. You could use this domain to access the backend from your `login.js` part. The domain is shown in your dashboard. Another point is the `port` - in your case `5000`. This won't work, because Heroku assigns your backend project a "random" port with the env variable `PORT` as you can see in:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

You could change the login part to

```
    const response = await fetch("__REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PROJECT_DOMAIN_FROM_HEROKU_DASHBOARD__/api/auth/login", {
```

or

```
    const response = await fetch("/api/auth/login", {
```

**UPDATE**

Another thing is your routing:
The grouped routes won't work this way. You have to group them for your API structure with routers.

Do get your structure working, you could use this part:

```
// Available Routes
const apiRouter = express.Router();
const authRouter = express.Router();
const notesRouter = express.Router();
authRouter.use("/auth", require('./routes/auth'));
notesRouter.use("/notes", require('./routes/notes'));
apiRouter.use(authRouter);
apiRouter.use(notesRouter);
app.use("/api", apiRouter);
```

In your code it's starting at line 16 which you can replace with the code above and it should work. Right now, your grouped structure doesn't match the frontend structure of your URLs.

Comment: I tried what you said but it is still not working. It's giving this error                                  
                                                                                                                                           
(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
login:1 
        
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
WebSocketClient.js:16)

Comment: Which url are you using? Where is the 404 - it is during the `await fetch` or during the load of other parts?

Comment: During the login `await fetch`. This is the code await fetch url `const response = await fetch("/api/auth/login"`

Comment: You can check my full code it is published on github [link](https://github.com/JenilBheda/iNotebook-frontend) and here is my front-end : [link](https://inotebook-first-project.herokuapp.com/login)

Comment: I've updated the post. Take a look at it please

Comment: Thanks for the help. Problem is solved actually I was not uploading my backend properly on Heroku and as you mentioned I was also not linking my front-end to my Heroku backend server that's why I was facing the problem. You Helped me a lot Thank you So much.